# Is there another scene with a four-handed Terminator in the Terminator films?

Tags: terminator-series

This [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218782/why-is-the-t-1000-humanoid) shows an image where a specific model of the [Humanoid Hunter Killer Terminator](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Humanoid_Hunter_Killer) (in this case a T-1000) has four hands.

[image]

Are there any other appearances of a humanoid (any model) with four hands in any Terminator movie?

Comment: You're asking two slightly different questions here - "do we see any other Terminators with four hands", and "do Terminators *usually* have four hands". One does not imply the other.

Comment: But I would be also interested in another scene of the same Humanoid using four hands @F1Krazy. Do you have any suggestion for improving my post please? :)

Comment: I think the questions are similar enough that you can ask both without it being too broad. All you need to do is edit the question to make it clearer that you want to know both, and whoever answers this should be able to comfortably answer both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sequel films, TV show and comics, the answer is no, we don't see another four-handed Terminator.

The T-1000 Terminators and its successors such as the [T-1001](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Catherine_Weaver) (pictured below), [T-3000](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/T-3000) and [T-5000](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/T-5000) certainly *possess* this capacity, but we simply don't see them doing it again.

[image]

---

Within the spin-off novels, we're introduced to the [T-XA](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/T-XA). This late-model Terminator is capable of splitting parts of itself off into sub or 'pseudo' humanoid units, which *can each have their own hands* (totalling four or more). This technically meets the letter of your question, but not the spirit.

> Baxter had drawn a handgun and he started firing, perhaps ten times in
> a matter of seconds. The bullets did the pseudo-dog little harm as it
> reformed, but it stopped in its tracks under the hail of accurate
> fire, letting the humans get a few more yards ahead. Meanwhile, **the
> pseudo-man and -woman components of the T-XA came after them, both of
> them fully recovered, the man firing the laser rifle.** This time, the
> beam nailed Baxter, drilling through his torso and setting him alight.
>
> "Robert!" Jade shouted, rushing back to catch his smoking body as it
> fell. She hefted him over her shoulder, running under his weight
> without seeming impeded.
>
> <sup><sub>[Terminator 2: The New John Connor Chronicles Dark Futures](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Futures)</sub></sup>